# whatsApp send message let user edit the message in ios , in android it doesn't

Tags: android, ios, swift, whatsapp

Is there a way to send the message directly after the user select a contact instead of letting him edit the message in a textField?Like in Android,it directly sends it after you pick a contact , I only found that code and it lets the user edit the message first-

```
let whatsappURL = NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?text=Hello%2C%20World!")
if (UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(whatsappURL!)) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(whatsappURL !)
   }
```

Comment: as noted here [Whatsapp Documentation](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013), no. Its not possible. The text will only be pre-filled but not send.

Comment: they should unify their app in both android and ios , thanks anyway (Y) (Y)

Comment: I will add that as an answer, please accept that one. Thank you and no problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as noted here [Whatsapp Documentation](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013), no. Its not possible. 
The text will only be pre-filled but not send.